# Positioning Popup window in Android correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I'm stuck with the Popup window positioning. I'm showing my popup window on click of a Button. I want it should be positioned according to space available. Also if my button is at center it should be below the button. Below is my code for this thing. Please let me know where i'm wrong. Thank you.

```
mBtnPopUp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ListView mListView = (ListView) mPopUpView.findViewById(R.id.pop_up_list_view);
            mListView.setAdapter(mPopupListAdapter);
            Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.alert_light_frame);
            mPopupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
            // mPopupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

            showLikeQuickAction(0, 0);
            mPopupWindow.showAsDropDown(mBtnPopUp);
        }
    });

    mPopupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
public void showLikeQuickAction(int xOffset, int yOffset)
{

    int[] location = new int[2];
    mBtnPopUp.getLocationOnScreen(location);

    Rect anchorRect = new Rect(location[0], location[1], location[0] + mBtnPopUp.getWidth(), location[1] + mBtnPopUp.getHeight());

    mBtnPopUp.measure(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    int rootWidth = mBtnPopUp.getMeasuredWidth();
    int rootHeight = mBtnPopUp.getMeasuredHeight();

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    int screenWidth = mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();


    int xPos = screenWidth - rootWidth + xOffset;
    int yPos = anchorRect.top - rootHeight + yOffset;

    if(rootWidth > anchorRect.right - anchorRect.left)
    {
        // right
        xPos = anchorRect.right - rootWidth;
    }
    else
    {
        // left
        xPos = anchorRect.left + 15;
    }

    if(xPos + rootWidth > screenWidth)
        xPos = screenWidth - rootWidth - 20;

    // display on bottom
    if(rootHeight > anchorRect.top)
    {
        yPos = anchorRect.bottom + yOffset;
        // mPopupWindow.setAnimationStyle(R.style.Animations_GrowFromTop);
    }

    mPopupWindow.showAtLocation(mBtnPopUp, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, xPos, yPos);
}
```

Thank you..

Comment: Have got the solution of this problem?? if yes,please provide me solution

Comment: Have you got solution ?

Answer (score 4):

I know its quiet late, but i hope it will help someone.

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();                
int popupWidth = 500;//ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
int popupHeight = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);

PopupWindow attachmentPopup = new PopupWindow(this);
attachmentPopup.setFocusable(true);
attachmentPopup.setWidth(popupWidth);
attachmentPopup.setHeight(popupHeight);         
attachmentPopup.setContentView(popupView);
attachmentPopup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
attachmentPopup.showAsDropDown(v, -5, 0);
```

It will position your popup window according to the position of your button.

Comment: Have you tested this when 
a) locale of the Android device this is running on is right-to-left such as Arabic?
b) the app itself is in 'Multi WIndow' or 'Pop-up window' mode and its top-left corner is NOT the top-left corner of the whole screen?  From my experience, the code above does not work in those two cases.

Answer (score 3):

```
public void downloadBtnSelected(View anchor) {
    final ListPopupWindow lpw = new ListPopupWindow(this);
    String[] data = { ".png", ".pdf", ".jpg", ".jpeg" };
    PopupAdapter pa = new PopupAdapter(data, this);
    lpw.setAdapter(pa);

    //setting up an anchor view
    lpw.setAnchorView(anchor);

    //Setting measure specifications. I'v used this mesure specs to display my
    //ListView as wide as my anchor view is
    lpw.setHeight(android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lpw.setWidth(anchor.getRight() - anchor.getLeft());

    // Background is needed. You can use your own drawable or make a 9patch.
    // I'v used a custom btn drawable. looks nice.
    lpw.setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.btn_default));

    // Offset between anchor view and popupWindow
    lpw.setVerticalOffset(3); 

    lpw.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // Our action.....
            lpw.dismiss();

        }
    });
    lpw.show();

}
```

and the button with an onClickListener to call this method:

```
Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        downloadBtnSelected(v);
    }
});
```

this code let's you to show a popup below btn
the popup width will be the same as the button one.
if you want to fill the screen width- set width=LinearLayout.MATCH_PARENT
popup menu will be displayed below the anchor view if space, and beyond if there is no space below

Answer (score 1):

this code will show perfect popup in center of you specific view

```
// click event of specific view
  @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        super.onClick(v);
       if (v == lin_filterActionbar) {
            PopupWindow popupwindow_obj; // create object
            popupwindow_obj = dialog_AllergiesSelect(RR_HomeActivity.this,lin_filterActionbar);
            popupwindow_obj.showAsDropDown(lin_filterActionbar);

        } 
    }



 private PopupWindow dialog_AllergiesSelect(Context context,LinearLayout lin) {

        final PopupWindow dialog_AllergiesSelect = new PopupWindow(this);

        View v = View.inflate(context, R.layout.dialog_filter_actionbar, null);
        dialog_AllergiesSelect.setContentView(v);
        dialog_AllergiesSelect.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dialog_AllergiesSelect.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dialog_AllergiesSelect.setFocusable(true);

//        TextView lis_testSelection = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dialogfilter_txt_filter);
//        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lin_laLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) (sunApplication.getDeviceWidth() - (sunApplication.getDeviceScale() * dialog_width_dvide_allerges_spinner_width)), (int) (sunApplication.getDeviceHeight() - (sunApplication.getDeviceScale() * dialog_width_dvide_allerges_height)));
//        lis_testSelection.setLayoutParams(lin_laLayoutParams);

        // Some offset to align the popup a bit to the right, and a bit down, relative to button's position.
        int OFFSET_X = 0;
        int OFFSET_Y = 0;

        // Clear the default translucent background
        dialog_AllergiesSelect.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

        // Displaying the popup at the specified location, + offsets.
        //dialog_AllergiesSelect.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.C, p.x + OFFSET_X, p.y + OFFSET_Y);

        Rect location = locateView(lin);

        dialog_AllergiesSelect.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER, 0, location.bottom);

        // Getting a reference to Close button, and close the popup when clicked.

        return dialog_AllergiesSelect;

    }
    public static Rect locateView(View v)
    {
        int[] loc_int = new int[2];
        if (v == null) return null;
        try
        {
            v.getLocationOnScreen(loc_int);
        } catch (NullPointerException npe)
        {
            //Happens when the view doesn't exist on screen anymore.
            return null;
        }
        Rect location = new Rect();
        location.left = loc_int[0];
        location.top = loc_int[1];
        location.right = location.left + v.getWidth();
        location.bottom = location.top + v.getHeight();
        return location;
    }
```

Comment: Use "showAsDropDown" not "showAtLocation" . It gives better UI.

Answer (score 0):

For custom popup make one XML file named

cust_toast_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toast_layout_root"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="45dp" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="200dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in java file where you want this popup add below code

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cust_toast_layout,
                               (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));



TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
//text.setText("Excellent !!!");
text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.right_ans);
Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.setView(layout);
toast.show();
```

On buttonclick you can call one method and in that method include this code.
You can make changes as per your requirements through edit in xml file.

Comment: Thanks Zeel for your response but i think that you don't get my problem. I'm using the Popup window which i want to position below or above the button w.r.t. the position on button in the screen. for ex. If my button is above the center of screen my popup window should appear at the bottom of button.

Comment: Is your button position fix?

Comment: You can set weight attribute in condition operator for this. But for popup i have not try yet. If you try then let me know that it is working or not.

Comment: This answer is unrelated with the posted question!